# Input text field value behavior after Get request

Tags: python, django

I have this form

```
<form class="form-inline" type="get" action=".">

         <input id="excel_input" class="form-control" type="text"  name="excel_input" value="0">
         <input class="btn" type="submit" name="excelbutton" value="excelbuttonclicked"
                    onclick='document.getElementById("excel_input").value = "1";'><i class="ion ion-search"></i></input>

 </form>
```

I want to get the value "1" when the  excelbutton clicked in the Get request in order to export an excel file. I want to use the Get request because in this point I have a ready query set , the query set user sees on the screen.
I use the commands

```
request.GET.get('excel_input', None)
if excel_string not in ['0', None]:
    testxlsxwriter(d_list)
```

to get the value of the input field and export the excel file. The problem is that I get the value "1" from the input field on button click , but then I always get the value "1" on get requests( refresh , next page etc.
I see the value "0" on screen on refresh but I get the value "1" on my view
I also tried javascript with no luck

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("excel_input").value = "0";
}
```

Can someone help me please to understand how get request works with this input element?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Comment: Using GET method will update url of your page to something like `?excel_input=1`. That is why subsequence requests always have `excel_input=1`. You can verify by looking to address bar after clicking `excelbutton`. Instead of using form, why don't you use `<a href="your_url?excel_input=1" target="_blank">Export Excel</a>`? This solution will open new window to download exported Excel file instead of changing current page.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I used this form method for a global search on all views in my app. I check if search box has value and modify the query set. But in this case I edit the input box. In excel case I set value by javascript. Maybe this is the difference.